# unable to hide div in angular js using ng-if

Tags: html, angularjs

unable to hide div on loading page.
I want to show the div if the value of array is empty.

```
    <div ng-hide="loading"  ng-if="users== null || users.length === 0" >
        <h3>No Result Found</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: remove `ng-hide` and check.

Comment: combine expressions together: `loading && (users==null || users.length===0)`

Comment: use one of the directive ng-hide or ng-if according to your condition

Comment: @everyone who is saying don't use ng-hide with ng-if can you explain why?

Comment: @jitender simply pointless, `ng-if` removes DOM, `ng-hide` sets its display to _none_. Why bother hiding it, when DOM will be removed?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey yup i knew but how this will help OP to solve current problem?

Comment: @jitender there is usually a confusion of using `ng-hide` and `ng-show` (one needs to be true, while another one false), something similar can occur here, where `loading` might not be set correctly, it's better for it to be in the same expression

Comment: @AlekseySolovey i am agree but that's not the case here is simple show the message if array is empty and loading is not in progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you should do.

```
//This will check if loading is false and Users are not undefined || less than equal to 0 (empty array)
<div ng-if="!loading || !users || users.length <= 0">
    <h3>No Result Found</h3>
</div>

//Show data if users are defined and length is greater than 0
<div ng-if="users && users.length > 0">
        <h3>Data</h3>
</div>
```

Using ng-show and ng-hide

```
//Show if loading is true or users are undefined or users are empty
//Hide if loading is false or users are defined or users are not empty
<div ng-show="loading || !users || users.length <= 0"
     ng-hide="!loading || users || users.length > 0">
        <h3>No Result Found</h3>
</div>

//Show if users are defined and length is greater than 0
//Hide if loading is true or users are undefined or users are empty
<div ng-show="users && users.length > 0"
     ng-hide="loading || !users || users.length <= 0">
        <h3>Data</h3>
</div>
```

ng-hide/show just sets the display property of the element to "none" whereas, ng-if removes the element from the dom

Comment: not working. there is two div one is for to display result and one is for no result.. unable to understand where to use ng-if

Comment: @user3074158 check my answer now. I have updated it and explained everything.

Comment: where is define the scope of loading ?

Comment: That you will be doing it in your controller. As you haven't given us your code so I am assuming that "loading" is a $scope variable and defined already somewhere in your code just like users array.

Comment: In controller, i mentioned this two lines only                                
        $scope.users = [];
 $scope.loading = [] ;

Comment: and response m getting is []

Comment: You need learn the basics of angular first. What you need the loading variable to be? what type do you want it to be? Its a broad question.

Comment: ng-if is not working that's y m using ng hide using loading variable

Comment: Use this : 
<div ng-if="!users || users.length <= 0">
    <h3>No Result Found</h3>
</div>

//Show data if users are defined and length is greater than 0
<div ng-if="users && users.length > 0">
        <h3>Data</h3>
</div>

Comment: its working i already did this. but the problem is no result appears on refresh. so first time i want hide this div. ng-if="!users || users.length <= 0" ng-hide="!loading"

Comment: in controller scope of loading is false. so if conditon is true scope of variable need to be true and i dont know how to do that

Comment: hey thanx Hey24sheep. i did some changes is controller                                        if (response.data.length > 0 ){
      $scope.users = response.data;
      $scope.loading = true;
    }else
    {
     $scope.users = [];
     $scope.loading = false;
    }

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad it worked. Don't forget to accept my answer and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you - use `&&` or `||` as per your case here -

```
<div ng-hide="loading && users.length == 0">
    <h3>No Result Found</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `Boolean([]) === true`, so if `users` is a defined array, the above expression may be truthy even if the array is empty.

Comment: Yeah, that's what he wants. ng-hide will hide the div if users array isn't empty.

Comment: Again, an empty array in JS evaluates as boolean `true`, unlike in PHP for example. So the `div` would be hidden as long as the array is defined, regardless if its empty or not. Simply try it.

Comment: okay, So, here, we update it with - `users.length`. Thank You!

Comment: not working. there is two div one is for to display result and one is for no result.. unable to understand where to use ng-if

Comment: use this for your another div - `ng-show="users.length > 0"`, also updated current div code.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you

```
<div ng-if="!loading && (typeof(users) === 'undefined'  || users== null || users.length === 0)" >
    <h3>No Result Found</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: not working. there is two div one is for to display result and one is for no result.. unable to understand where to use ng-if

Comment: I think you should check value of $scope.loading. Why not upload whole code on plunker?

Comment: <div class="container" ng-hide="" ng-repeat="user in users" >            
 here m displaying result </div>                                                                          
<div ng-if="!user || user.length <= 0">
            <h3>No Result Found</h3>
 </div>